# Find the minimum of $f(x) = |1-\cos(x)|+|1-\sin(x)|$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Assume $x \in [0,2\pi)$ any other solutions would occur because the periodic nature of $\sin$ and $\cos$.

This is a small sub problem for a problem I am currently working on.

The problem should not be too difficult, but I'm not sure how to approach it since I can not just take a derivative. Any help or hints are appreciated.

The solution is $\frac{\pi}{4}$ I just can't seem to justify it.

Comment: Hint: $\cos x \leqslant 1$ and $\sin x \leqslant 1$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint:

For $x \in [0, \pi /2]$, $1-cos(x)$ is positive, so $$|1-cos(x)|=1-cos(x)$$ and $1-sin(x)$ positive, so $$|1-sin(x)|=1-sin(x)$$
Now you can take the derivative for $x \in  [0, \pi /2]$.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for thanks.

Answer (score 2):

**HINT:**

See when sine and cossine is positive and then
$$f(x) = 2-(\cos x + \sin x)=2-\sqrt{2}\sin\left(\pi + \frac{x}{4}\right)$$

What happen when sin is $1$ or $-1$ ?

Answer (score 0):

Due to the absolute value operation $|...|$ you have to compare different cases:
- When is $1-cos(x)$ positive and when negative? When is $1-sin(x)$ positive and when negative?
- You will have 4 different cases
Then you can omit the operations $|...|$ and derive $f(x)$ by $x$. Finally, find the solutions of $f'(x)$ by respecting the cases you have analyzed.

Comment: This problem is easier than you think!